# My chrome browser freezes frequently

Tags: google-chrome

My chrome browser freezes frequently, and I have no idea what is wrong. I am running 64-bit Window 8.1, and my Chrome browser is 32.0.1700.102 m.

What I have tried so far:

1. I checked other browsers like firefox, and they work just fine!
2. I cleared cache and browsing history.
3. I ran chrome with extensions disabled (`--disable-extensions`)
4. I ran chrome with plugins disabled (`--safe-plugins`)
5. I disabled the 'hardware acceleration' from Setting | System | Use hardware acceleration when available
6. I uninstalled and installed chrome again!

It's very strange, but Chrome still freezes from time to time. Is there any log file that I can check to find out what the actual problem is?

Edit:

As suggested by @Rudolph, I ran chrome with logging on (`--enable-logging --v=1`), and here is the output windows. It seems the error is: ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENT

How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Enable logging: http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging. Also check your resource utilization while chrome is running. Also state what OS you are using incl, 32bit or 64 bit.

Comment: I've also had issues with this since the recent update. An example would be if I click a link to open in a new tab the tab opens, the url box and the title of the tab are updated correctly, but the content doesn't change.

Comment: Prevorius realease was a bit buggy, maybe they did not fix all of it. If it started freeze recently, wair for a new relase.